# FullCalendar - How to have Different clickEvent per eventSource

Tags: fullcalendar

I am looking for a way to have a different eventClick depending on the eventSource and to have some eventSources that do not have an eventClick.  This way I can have an event open a different pop up depending on it's source.

I started with this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                height: 600,
                theme: true,
                eventSources: [
                    {
                    url: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
                    className: 'fc-event-title-event'                   
                    } ,
                    {
                    url: 'testCalendar',
                    color: 'red',
                    currentTimezone: 'America/New_York',
                    editable: true                   
                    } 

            ],

            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view ) {                        
                        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
                        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
                        alert('View: ' + view.name);

                        //window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                        return false;
                    },      

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $('#loading').show();
                }else{
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }           
        });     
    });
```

The eventClick is fired for both sources.  It seems there would be a way to customize the eventClick per source, but I am not seeing it in the documentation nor in countless searches in stackoverflow and google.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm I don't think that `eventSources` has an option for `eventClick`. You could use the `calEvent` object and check it's `source` to determine how to handle the click event. Outside of that I don't think fullcalendar has the built in functionality you're looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Checking the calEvent.source.url will give me the control I need.  Good Idea.   Still seems like a per eventSource eventClick could be useful.  Thank you.